# Pymongo w=1 with continue_on_error

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection of tweets. I want to insert a list of tweets into this collection. The new list may have some duplicate tweets as well and I want to ensure that duplicate tweets do not get written but all remaining does. To achieve this, I'm using following code.

```
mongoPayload = <list of tweets>
committedTweetIDs = db.tweets.insert(mongoPayload, w=1, continue_on_error=True)
print "%d documents committed" % len(committedTweetIDs)
```

The above code snippet should work. However, the behavior I'm getting is that second line generated DuplicateKeyError. I don't know what this is happening since, I mentioned continue_on_error.

What I want in the end is for Mongo to commit all the non-duplicate documents and return to me (as acknowledgement) tweetIDs of all the documents written to the journal.

Comment: That second line isn't valid Python. You can't put a positional argument after a keyword argument (`SyntaxError`). Can you show us what the line really looks like? If you are doing something like `continue_on_error=some_variable`, are you sure `some_variable` is true?

Comment: Sorry, yes. `continue_on_error=True should` be there. My mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even with `continue_on_error=True`, PyMongo will raise a DuplicateKeyError if MongoDB tells it that you tried to insert a document with a duplicate `_id`. However, with `continue_on_error=True`, the server **has** attempted to insert all the documents in your list, instead of aborting the operation on the first error. The `error_document` attribute of the exception tells you the **last** duplicate `_id` in your list of documents.

Unfortunately you cannot determine how many documents succeeded and failed in total when you do a bulk insert. [MongoDB 2.6 and PyMongo 2.7 will address this in the next release](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-554) when we implement bulk write operations.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I saw the release notes of 2.6 and it was written that user can have much better control on Bulk Inserts and failure conditions.